# How to open jquery tooltip at mouse location, and leave it there

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tooltip

My problem is that I have a list of dynamic objects, which have tooltips made with jquery tooltip. I would want to open the tooltip like when using `track:true`, at the mouse cursor location. The objects are events in jquery weekCalendar.

But I do not want to move the tooltip according to the cursor after this. I want the tooltip to disappear normally, when exiting the hover-area.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

**I tried:**
Setting the option track to false on the onMouseOver-event of the item and setting it back to true on mouseOut. Didn't work. The option didn't become valid when the tooltip first appeared. Verified this by removing the back to true setting in the mouseOut. The tooltip tracked on first appearance, but not after that.

So I create the tooltip like so:

```
$item.tooltip({
     items: $event,
     track: true,
         ...
```

And then in the hover event:

```
var item = $(event.target);
item.tooltip( "option", "track", false );
```

But this approach only works on the next tooltip to be opened, not the one already open, which will still keep following the cursor.

Comment: show the code you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the position property of jQuery UI for setting the position of tooltip.
Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxLu/9/)

**HTML**

```
    <input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
      $(document).tooltip();
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
      $(document).tooltip("option", "position", {
          my: "left+3 bottom-3",
          of: event
      });
  });
```

Comment: Did not work. The tooltip opened at the default location and not near the mouse.

Comment: I checked the demo from two devices and in both it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not using it that way. I set the tooltip dynamically for different items needing it. Its not just the title attribute, but large amounts of data. The $event in my code refers to a calendar-event. It works for the title tooltips yes.

Comment: Ok was testing more, on my calendar-events, I did not get the tooltip to work on the mouseMove-event, but it basically worked on the hover-event. But again on the next tooltip to appear. So the tooltip would appear where you last hovered on another element.

Comment: Cannot really create a fiddle of it, it cannot be seperated from the application and still work. It has alot of JSON dependencies etc.

Comment: Create a fiddle with sample data then.